# How to grab empty value from document.getElementByID('something').value

Tags: javascript

I'm want to have a conditional if the value is empty. But when I click on the button now, and I have value on either of the fields, it's prompts the message to enter a value. Thanks!

I tried to make them equal to an empty string

```
let fieldValue1 = document.getElementById('something1').value;
let fieldValue2 = document.getElementById('something2').value;

if (fieldValue1 == " " && fieldValue2 == " ") {

  document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML = "Please enter either fieldValue1 or fieldValue2"
}
```

The message should prompt only if both field values are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the message to prompt only if both fields are empty, couldn't you just just check like this:

```
if(!fieldValue1 && !fieldValue2)
{
 document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML = "Please enter either fieldValue1 or
                                                 fieldValue2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fieldValue1 == " "` will only work if there is 1 space in the field (like if you pressed the space bar once).

You can do:

```
fieldValue1 == "" && fieldValue2 == ""
```

...which means "is equal to an empty string". Or, since an empty string is "falsy" in JavaScript, you can just do:

```
!fieldValue1 && !fieldValue2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the string you are checking for is one space, not an empty string. You need to check for `''`, not `' '`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a fix for your codes.

```
let fieldValue1 = document.getElementById('something1').value;
let fieldValue2 = document.getElementById('something2').value;

if (fieldValue1 === "" && fieldValue2 === "") {

    document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML = "Please enter either fieldValue1 or fieldValue2"
}
```

You just need to check for empty fields, which "" with no space in between is needed.